# C# Regex to convert yyyyMMddhhmm

Tags: c#, regex

Currently I'm converting yyyyMMdd to yyyy-MM-dd using the following RegEx:

```
Regex.Replace(inputString, @"(\w{4})(\w{2})(\w{2})", @"$1-$2-$3");
```

not really knowing anything about Regex, I need to convert yyyyMMddhhmm to yyyy-MM-dd hh:ss

Can someone help me with this.
Thank you
Rodney

Comment: How mins to seconds is possible through regex?

Answer (score 5):

Don't use Regex or `String`- but `DateTime` methods to convert a `String` to `DateTime` and back to `String`:

```
string dtStr = "20151005";
DateTime date = DateTime.ParseExact(dtStr, "yyyyMMdd", DateTimeFormatInfo.InvariantInfo);
string result = date.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");

dtStr = "201510051445";
date = DateTime.ParseExact(dtStr, "yyyyMMddHHmm", DateTimeFormatInfo.InvariantInfo);
result = date.ToString(" yyyy-MM-dd hh:ss");
```

Answer (score 0):

- The `\w` is used for matching one single word-character like `A`, `D`, `1` and `3`, which in your case is a little bit strange. I should prefer `\d` which will match only digits.
- The curly brackets `{` and `}` are used for counting. `{4}` means: match four times.
- The round brackets `(` and `)` are for grouping and capturing.

So the construct `\d{4}` means: Match four digits. And `(\d{4})` means: match 4 digits as one group (in your case: the first group).

```
Regex.Replace(inputString, @"(\d{4})(\d{2})(\d{2})(\d{2})(\d{2})", @"$1-$2-$3 $4:$5");
```

For much, much more information, take a look here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az24scfc(v=vs.110).aspx

Of course there are other solutions without regular expressions for parsing DateTime-values, like [DateTime.ParseExact(...)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.parseexact(v=vs.110).aspx) and [DateTime.ToString(format)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zdtaw1bw(v=vs.110).aspx).